# Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy policy would block the window.postMessage call error with Sign in with Google

Tags: reactjs, firebase, cross-origin-opener-policy, sign-in-with-google

I have implemented Sign in with Google using popup UX mode for a React site hosted on Firebase.  I am able to sign in, however, each time I sign in on localhost:3000 or on a deployed version of my site, I get this error:

`Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy policy would block the window.postMessage call.`

I have attempted to set Cross Origin Opener Policy as detailed [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/get-google-api-clientid#cross_origin_opener_policy).  In setting this up, my firebase.json file looks like this:

```
{
    "database": {
        "rules": "database.rules.json"
    },
    "functions": {
        "predeploy": ["npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"],
        "source": "functions"
    },
    "hosting": [
        {
            "target": "sandbox",
            "public": "build",
            "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
            "rewrites": [
                {
                    "source": "**",
                    "destination": "/index.html",
                    "headers": [
                        {
                            "key": "Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy",
                            "value": "same-origin-allow-popups"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "headers": [
                {
                    "source": "**",
                    "headers": [
                        {
                            "key": "Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy",
                            "value": "same-origin-allow-popups"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "target": "production",
            "public": "build",
            "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
            "rewrites": [
                {
                    "source": "**",
                    "destination": "/index.html",
                    "headers": [
                        {
                            "key": "Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy",
                            "value": "same-origin-allow-popups"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "headers": [
                {
                    "source": "**",
                    "headers": [
                        {
                            "key": "Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy",
                            "value": "same-origin-allow-popups"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "storage": {
        "rules": "storage.rules"
    },
    "emulators": {
        "auth": {
            "port": 9099
        },
        "functions": {
            "port": 5001
        },
        "database": {
            "port": 9000
        },
        "hosting": {
            "port": 5000
        },
        "storage": {
            "port": 9199
        },
        "ui": {
            "enabled": true
        },
        "singleProjectMode": true
    }
}
```

In trying to troubleshoot this further, I've also added this line to my index.html file in the header element:

`<meta http-equiv="Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy" content="same-origin-allow-popups">`

Unfortunately, I continue to get the same error when signing in whether I am on localhost:3000 or deployed to my sandbox target.  Any suggestions on what I may be missing?

Answer (score 0):

I've also encountered this issue, from what I was able to debug it originates from the popup iframe trying to communicate with the parent window. From my understanding its not possible to do if it implements "same-origin" COOP header server wide (based on other requests made).
There is related topic open on github [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/51135)

I was not able to determine what's the actual message that OAuth iframe is trying to post, it doesn't break my login flow either.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it turned out that I had the wrong URIs inside my 'Authorized JavaScript origins' and 'Authorized redirect URIs' in google cloud. I had them set to http://localhost:5000 when I was suppose to be using:

http://localhost:3000,
http://localhost:3000/login,
http://localhost:3000/register.

Comment: I entered the correct URIs in google cloud dashboard. However, I am getting the same error in the console. Is that something I missed? Or any other workaround for this?

Answer (score -1):

I may be late but I wanted to reply because it took me a long time to find the solution to this problem.
By the way, on the react side, it's possible with this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-login
However, you need to load the google api scripts in before using it.

here's how to proceed:

```
1- Install the gapi-script package as follows :

npm instal gapi-script
```

2- load and initialize google api script in your ReactJs app as follows:

```js
import { gapi } from "gapi-script";
import React, {useEffect} from 'react'

function App(){

 const initializeGapi = () => {
    gapi.client.init({
      clientId: GAP_CLIENT_ID,
      scope: "",
    });
  };
  
  useEffect(() =>{
    // load and init google api scripts
    gapi.load("client:auth2", initializeGapi);
  })
  
  return (
    React.Fragment>
      <AppRoutes />
    <React.Fragment>
  ); 
}

export default App;
```

3- You can now continue using your react-google-login package.
You may get warning corns on your console, but the feature will work just fine.

Comment: this package has been deprecated