# Retrieve user data from Google sign in

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a google sign in button in my webpage. For that I have created a button in html page based on google html page on google console help.

Next, I coded in html a form and input fields. I have three files: one is index, second is css, and the third is login in html and its css.

Then I created code in javascript to fetch user data after sign in from google. I register in google console and get the client id and place it in meta tag. I gave javascript origin and redirect origin address of my site.

The whole process is correct. The sign in process completed fully: it gets signed in properly and shows the email and image on then button. But, it does not retrieve data in console.

The console after sign in gives the following error: `client:268 Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy policy would block the window.postMessage call`.

I tried all chat gpt and all stack overflow questions but it was not solved yet. The above error is showing in console of google chrome.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy" content="same-origin-allow-popups">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/login.css">
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
    <script src="js/login.js"></script>
    <div id="g_id_onload" data-client_id="970963878365-1dorojn0774tgekijnmb475h09gh9p0p.apps.googleusercontent.com">
    </div>
    <title>Login</title>
    <style>
        label {
            display: block;
            margin-top: 1rem;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="form" id="form">
            <form>
                <!-- Your login form fields here -->

                <!-- Google Sign-In divs -->

                <div class="g_id_signin" data-type="standard" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>

                <!-- Other elements -->

                <button data-onsuccess="signOut()">Sign out</button>

                <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
                <input id="firstName" type="text" autocomplete="given-name" />

                <label for="image">Last Name:</label>
                <input id="image" type="text" autocomplete="family-name" />

                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input id="email" type="email" autocomplete="off" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
<script>
    // Google Sign-in (new)
    function onSignIn(googleUser) {
        var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
        console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
        console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
        console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail()); // This is null if the 'email' scope is not present.
    };
    //sign out button
    function signOut() {
        var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
        auth2.signOut().then(function () {
            alert("You have been signed out successfully");
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: client:268 Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy policy would block the window.postMessage call.

Comment: Try this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76555769/google-sign-in-not-working-in-next-js-with-firebase-due-to-cross-origin-opener-p

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the Cross-Origin Opener Policy. To fix this problem you need to add this code inside the HTML tag and Add a try-catch block.

```
<meta http-equiv="Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy" content="same-origin-allow-popups">
```

Add handle errors in the onSignIn function.

```
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
    try {
        var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId());
        console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
        console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
        console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail());
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error during sign-in:', error);
    }
}
```

I hope this will solve your problem.